# java producer-consumer multithreading benchmark. Why does it stop?

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking

Please, help me with my problem.

I have java program - test for server, something like echo, a benchmark tool.

To simplify:

I send to server 100 messages from a different number of threads (simulate real-world producers, for example, from 10 clients or 1, doesn't really matter) and receive responses.

I have the same situation with consumers (comsumer=thread). Producers and consumers generate events (message received from... message sent from... etc.)

My main implements MyEvenListener, with onMessage() and counts everything up.

My problem is that I can not receive all 100 messages back and count them, because the program stops after messages are sent. I know that this is something simple, but can't figure out how to fix it. :(

here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.init();
}
private int mesReceved=0;
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    Sender s = new Sender(15,this);
    Resender r = new Resender(15,this);
    r.createThreads();
    r.startThreads();
    s.createThreads();
    s.startThreads();
    System.out.println(mesReceved);

}
public void onEvent(String string) {
    mesReceved++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem in this code.

Can you try simplifying the problem e.g. less threads until the problem stops occurring.

In the simplest case e.g. with 4 threads, where this happens

- take a thread stack,
- use debugging or
- add logging to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The problem is, when program goes to System.out.println(mesReceved); it print 0  and ends. I doesn't receve all responses. I hope, I'm right? Anyway, I'll try now to change code a little bit, and try, thanks.

Comment: I would expect it to print 0 as you haven't recieved any message yet. I.e. you are not waiting for the threads to do anything, and you are using threads *because* you won't want to wait for them to finish.  If your program exits, perhaps your threads are daemon threads which means your program won't wait for them to finish either.

Comment: If I start s.createThreads(); s.startThreads(); from new thread in main, then make: newThread.join(); it still works the same, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to join() on the threads which you want to wait for, not the thread which started them.  A simpler solution is to not make the threads, daemon threads.

Comment: Maybe I didn't asked correctly what I want.  I want to count all messages received, count time send\receive, for this reason I want to stop program at some point till all messages are received and continue to work. I receive all messages and continue to analise them. Or, I'm wrong? I want to continue next step in main inly when, I have all messages received.

Comment: You need an `r.joinThreads()` which waits for the started threads to finish. I assume these are the threads you want to wait for?

Comment: Yes, but                   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  DummyClass c = new DummyClass();
  final Sender s = new Sender(1,c);
  final Resender r = new Resender(1,c);
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   
   public void run() {
    r.createThreads();
    r.startThreads();
    s.createThreads();
    s.startThreads();
   }
  });
  t.start();
  t.join();
  System.out.println("end");

 } I still have "end" printed.  Or I should not do this with new thread?

Comment: You want to wait on the senders and receivers so I don't see the point of waiting for an unreleated thread.

Comment: r.joinThreads() actually worked, thanks. But, Why this works, and when I tried to do as in previous my comment (just make different thread) didn't hepled.

Comment: Yes, I understand, When, I created that runnable it was responsible only for creating other threads, and when it's done, thread is over, so I clearly see "end". I had to join dirrect workers, but not this.!

Comment: +1 because the convo in the comments is obviously what helped here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually waiting for the threads to finish before leaving `main`? You should use `Thread.join` on all the created threads at the end of `main`, otherwise the main thread will just exit without waiting for the children to finish.

Comment: Yes, it was my problem, I was waiting on wrong thread. Simple mistake, but half day im this is spent. Thank's guys for helping.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Don't forget to mark the most useful answer as accepted for future readers to find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching your program? It could be completing successfully and then closing the window. There's a few ways around that.

One thought that comes to mind is that you could try a Thread.sleep(time) in your main. (Where time is how long you want it to wait in milliseconds. )

Comment: Thread.sleep(time) didn't helped, and I also don't know how much should I sleep.

Comment: Maybe I had a misunderstanding about what was going on. Again, I got the impression a window was closing. How long you should sleep for is arbitrary. It wasn't ever a solution, it was just intended to give you more time to read the output.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies in the fact the the main thread terminates after the setup process and therefore terminates all other threads.

An elegant way to wait for threads to finish their work is to use a high-level synchronization  aid, like [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

In this case, you could rewrite your init code like this:

```
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    producer = r.createThreads();
    r.startThreads();
    consumer = s.createThreads();
    s.startThreads();
    ...
    producer.getCountDownLatch().await();      // wait for all producers to finish
    consumer.getCountDownLatch().await();      // wait for all consumers to finish 
    // note: you could also encapsulate the latch and internally delegate the await
    // producer.await(); // nicer to read
}
```

On your Sender and Receiver classes, you create and maintain the CountDownLatch:

```
class Sender {
    final CountDownLatch sync;
    public Sender (int threadCount) {
        sync = new CountDownLatch(threadCount);
        ...
    }
    public CountDownLatch getCountDownLatch() {
        return sync;
    }
    // alternative
    public boolean await() {
        return sync.await();
    }
}
```

When you create the threads, you pass the countDownLatch to each runnable.
When they are done working, you decrement the latch:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    public MyRunnable(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
        ...
    } 
    public void run() {
        // DO STUFF
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

With this synchronization process in place, your program will only terminate when all producers and consumers have done their job.
Additionally. the `await` method can take a timeout as argument, sothat you can ensure program termination within some boundaries.
e.g. let all producers work, but wait only 5 minutes for the consumers:

```
public void init() {
    ...
    producer.getCountDownLatch().await();      // wait for all producers to finish
    boolean allFinished = consumer.getCountDownLatch().await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);      // wait 5 minutes for all consumers to finish.
    if (!allFinished) {
        // alert that not all consumers ended on time
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll read more about CountDownLatch today, about usecases, and will try. It looks like, good solution for me, but a little hard to understand. One more question, what benefit is gives to me, when I also solved this problem with just join()???

Comment: Just as an example, 'just join()' will let you wait forever in case one of your working threads does not finish for any reason.  Using concurrency tools lets you take control over your multithreaded system. For example, a `CountDownLatch` can help you start all threads exactly at the same time, which is helpful if you are investigating deadlocks. `CyclicBarrier` could help you do test in cycles/steps. You are doing multithreading *benchmarking*, so you need to understand and control the threads.

Comment: -1 because the statement about 'main' terminating other threads is just wrong. It is quite normal for 'main' to terminate and other non-daemon threads to keep the JVM alive.

Comment: @tim Bender could you then explain what is going on in *this* case ?  Please note that I wrote 'your problem...'. I'm not making a general statement.  IMO in  *this* case ` main ` is ending and terminating the  JVM.  If that's a wrong hypothesis, I look forward to learn  about the correct arguments.

Comment: Actually, in this case you don't even know that the OPs statement about t he program exiting is correct. The OP likely only thinks that because they see the sysout and can't tell that the producer/consumer threads are quietly finishing in the background. Regardless, the statement that X thread terminates Y thread will always be wrong unless `Thread.stop` or something silly like that is being invoked.

Comment: @TimBender I did some further research and you are correct. The main Thread will not terminate unless the application threads are marked as deamon threads. I guess we need to see the code of `Sender` and `Resender` to know what's going on.